# Host ASP.NET Application in Amazon Web Service

Tags: asp.net, .net, web-services, iis, amazon-web-services

I have ASP.NET C# Application and i want to host it in the cloud using Amazon Web service and MS SQL 2008 for Database. What should i do to host my application in the cloud ? Any Suggestion are appreciated. Thanks Guys ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I highly recommend Elastic Beanstalk for everyone who is new in AWS. It is easy to start with and gives you a lot's of managed service.

In your case:

- Beanstalk support the latest [IIS/C#/.NET framework combination](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers.html). See also: [Supported .NET Platforms](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/concepts.platforms.html#concepts.platforms.net)
- There is a Visual Studio plugin for AWS which has 1-click Beanstalk deployment capability.
- Beanstalk supports to have an RDS (AWS Managed) database. RDS Supports MS-SQL, MySQL, Oracle.

Here to start:
[Creating and Deploying Elastic Beanstalk Applications in .NET Using AWS Toolkit for Visual Studio](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_NET.html)

What you don't see:
You will get an out of the box solution. You can choose between a 1 instance and a HA setup. You can easily have several (dev,Test,Prod) systems. It will be easy to manage them.
It follows most of the AWS architectural, security best practices by default.

Personal note:
I'm using Visual Studio + AWS Plugin + Visual Studio Online + Elastic Beanstalk for my current project. Works together well!

Comment: Do you use Visual Studio Online (now: Visual Studio Team Services) also for automatic Build & Deploy?

Comment: No, I did use VSO only as a TFS server for source control. Back then (2015 May) I did not found an easy way to integrate the VSO build to a beanstalk deployment, but CI/CD wasn't really my scope. (I'm not saying you can't do it today.)

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I ended up with building in VSTS for now (it's very slow though). Then I deploy to a AWS Beanstalk Single Container Docker environment (ASP.NET 5!) by uploading a Dockerfile with the VSTS Build ID to be deployed, and a script in the Dockerfile downloads and extracts the zipped drop folder created and stored by VSTS.

Comment: Hi are You able to deploy aplication from VSO Build to Elastic Beanstalk?

Comment: I was using VS directly to deploy to Beanstalk. However VSO has post-build steps so I think it's possible. ( Like it would be possible from Jenkins.) I never did it myself.